# Drupal form API checkboxes hierarchy

Tags: forms, api, drupal-7, hierarchy, checkbox

I am trying to setup a configuration page consisting of hierarchical checkboxes like the following:

```
-Parent#1
  --option#1
  --option#2

-Parent#2
  --option#1
  --option#2
```

To achieve the above layout, I am using the following code:

```
$form['categories']['templates']['parent1'] =   array(
    '#type'         =>  'checkboxes',
    '#title'        =>  t('Select the appropriate actions for the form based on the indicated template'),
    '#options'      =>  array("Parent#1"),
    '#multiple'     =>  TRUE,
);
$form['categories']['templates']['parent1']['actions']  =   array(
    '#type'         =>  'checkboxes',
    '#options'      =>  array("P1 - option#1", "P1 - option#2"),
    '#multiple'     =>  TRUE,
);

$form['categories']['templates']['parent2'] =   array(
    '#type'         =>  'checkboxes',
    '#title'        =>  t('Select the appropriate actions for the form based on the indicated template'),
    '#options'      =>  array("Parent#2"),
    '#multiple'     =>  TRUE,
);
$form['categories']['templates']['parent2']['actions']  =   array(
    '#type'         =>  'checkboxes',
    '#options'      =>  array("P2 - option#1", "P2 - option#2"),
    '#multiple'     =>  TRUE,
);
```

But the effect I am getting to not as desired. I attached an image of what the code is generating:

[image]

Comment: You meant to add a parent chekcbox that checks all its children when clicked ?

Comment: Something like that. The children checkboxes are meant to become visible when the parent is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the new Form API feature, `#states` to achieve this.

Note that, for ease of use, I'm wrapping the conditional checkboxes with a `fieldset`.

```
<?php
  $form['categories']['templates']['parent1'] =   array(
    '#type'         =>  'checkboxes',
    '#title'        =>  t('Select the appropriate actions for the form based on the indicated template'),
    '#options'      =>  array(1 => 'Parent#1'), // Note this! You can't use 0 as a key in #options.
    '#multiple'     =>  TRUE,
  );
  $form['categories']['templates']['parent1']['wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Options for @option', array('@option' => 'Parent#1')),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="parent1[1]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE), // We use "parent1" and its Nth option. in above field, See #options in above checkboxes field.
      ),
    ),
  );
  $form['categories']['templates']['parent1']['wrapper']['actions']  =   array(
    '#type'         =>  'checkboxes',
    '#options'      =>  array("P1 - option#1", "P1 - option#2"), // This is also wrong. You must define a key => value pair for #options or somehow avoid using 0 as the key.
    '#multiple'     =>  TRUE,
  ); 
?>
```

You might want to use `#tree` => TRUE in the fieldsets to avoid Drupal from merging same keys' values together.

Also, you won't need `#multiple` in checkboxes field type.

**Update**

Example with node types:

```
<?php
$node_types = node_type_get_names();
$form['categories']['templates']['parent1'] =   array(
  '#type'         =>  'checkboxes',
  '#title'        =>  t('Select the appropriate actions for the form based on the indicated template'),
  '#options'      =>  $node_types,
);
foreach ($node_types as $type => $label) {
  $form['categories']['templates']['node-options'.$type] =   array(
  '#type'         =>  'checkboxes',
  '#title'        =>  t('Options for @type', array('@type' => $label)),
  '#options'      =>  array("Parent#1"),
  '#multiple'     =>  TRUE,
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="parent1['.$type.']"]' => array('checked' => TRUE), // We use "parent1" and its Nth option. in above field, See #options in above checkboxes field.
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Just one more crucial bit of help - can this be amended to dynamically loop through an array of node types on the website?